# Using minimal LXC containers as an advanced and secure chroot to isolate services

Tags: linux, security, gentoo, container

First of all I'm not a security expert, and I never used LXC before.

I'm trying to harden as much as possible a Gentoo hardened server. To do so, I'm thinking to use LXC, maybe combined with KVM, to isolate as much as possible network services.

I read the LXC unix manual page, but it's still pretty obscure to me how Linux containers are setup. Looking on the internet for more information, I've only found documentation about running an entire system inside a Linux container which isn't what I'd like to do.

What I want to use LXC for, is running just one application inside a container including only the strict minimal files / resources required by the application. I do **not** want to run an entire system inside a container, avoiding even having busybox.

For example, I'd like to isolate the `ntpd` service, as far as I know to be able to synchronize the system clock, I can't run it inside a VM. But I could run it inside a `chroot`, or I suppose I could run it inside a Linux container for a better isolation and security.
To do so I would have to:

1. Identify what files ntpd requires like when setting up a chroot jail.
2. This where I don't know what to do and how: LXC configuration, template, where to put my files to set up the container, etc.
3. Run it with `lxc-execute`

Is it something possible? What would be the various steps to build, run and manage such a container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Historically, LXC has had many showstopping security issues that prevent it from being truly isolated, but infrastructure enhancements in the mainline Linux kernel have alleviated most (if not all) of these concerns.

See [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LxcSecurity) for an overview of the security problems / enhancements that have been observed in successive Ubuntu releases bundling LXC.

I found [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E37355/html/ol_about_containers.html) Oracle Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel documentation to be particularly useful for explaining how to do application-level containers.

From the docs:

> Application containers are not created by using template scripts. Instead, an application container mounts all or part of the host's root file system to provide access to the binaries and libraries that the application requires. You use the lxc-execute command to invoke lxc-init (a cut-down version of /sbin/init) in the container. lxc-init mounts any required directories such as /proc, /dev/shm, and /dev/mqueue, executes the specified application program, and then waits for it to finish executing. When the application exits, the container instance ceases to exist.